# Add bi-grams to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of bi-grams like this:

```
[['a','b'],['e', ''f']]
```

Now I want to add these bigrams to a DataFrame with their frequencies like this:

```
  b  f
a|1  0
e|0  1
```

I tried doing this with the following code, but this raises an error, because the index doesn't exist yet. Is there a fast way to do this for really big data? (like 200000 bigrams)

```
matrixA = pd.DataFrame()

# Put the counts in a matrix
for elem in grams:
    tag1, tag2 = elem[0], elem[1]
    matrixA.loc[tag1, tag2] += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

bigrams = [[['a','b'],['e', 'f']], [['a','b'],['e', 'g']]]
pairs = []
for bg in bigrams:
    pairs.append((bg[0][0], bg[0][1]))
    pairs.append((bg[1][0], bg[1][1]))
c = Counter(pairs)

>>> pd.Series(c).unstack()  # optional:  .fillna(0)
    b   f   g
a   2 NaN NaN
e NaN   1   1
```

The above is for the intuition.  This can be wrapped up in a one line generator expression as follows:

```
pd.Series(Counter((bg[i][0], bg[i][1]) for bg in bigrams for i in range(2))).unstack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the collections package. Note that I changed the contents of the list to be tuples rather than lists. This is because Counter keys (like dict keys) must be hashable.

```
from collections import Counter

l = [('a','b'),('e', 'f')]
index, cols = zip(*l)
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=index, columns=cols)
c = Counter(l)

for (i, c), count in c.items():
    df.loc[i, c] = count
```