# Fast way to create pandas dataframe from pairs

Tags: python, pandas, tags

I have a big file of word/tag pairs saved like this:

```
This/DT gene/NN called/VBN gametocide/NN
```

Now I want to put these pairs into a DataFrame with their counts like this:

```
      DT | NN --
This|  1   0
Gene|  0   1
 :
```

I tried doing this with a dict that counts the pairs and then put it in the DataFrame:

```
file = open("data.txt", "r")

train = file.read()
words = train.split()

data = defaultdict(int)
for i in words:
    data[i] += 1

matrixB = pd.DataFrame()

for elem, count in data.items():
    word, tag = elem.split('/')
    matrixB.loc[tag, word] = count
```

But this takes a really long time (file has like 300000 of these). Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was wrong with the answers from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727992/add-bi-grams-to-a-pandas-dataframe)?

```
from collections import Counter

with open('data.txt') as f:
    train = f.read()
c = Counter(tuple(x.split('/')) for x in train.split())
s = pd.Series(c)
df = s.unstack().fillna(0)

print(df)
```

yields

```
            DT  NN  VBN
This         1   0    0
called       0   0    1
gametocide   0   1    0
gene         0   1    0
```

Comment: Nothing at all, was just still testing it all out before I saw your answer. This helped me al lot, thank you very much!

Comment: Great - glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I thought this question was remarkably similar... Why did you post twice?

```
from collection import Counter

text =  "This/DT gene/NN called/VBN gametocide/NN"

>>> pd.Series(Counter(tuple(pair.split('/')) for pair in text.split())).unstack().fillna(0)

            DT  NN  VBN
This         1   0    0
called       0   0    1
gametocide   0   1    0
gene         0   1    0
```